# How to use IOptions pattern for configuration in dotnet-isolated (net5.0) azure functions

Tags: configuration, azure-functions, .net-5

I'm attempting to port an existing Functions app from core3.1 v3 to net5.0 I but can't figure out how to get the IOptions configuration pattern to work.

The configuration in my `local.settings.json` is present in the configuration data, and I can get to it using GetEnvironmentVariable. Still, the following does not bind the values to the IOptions configuration like it used to.

```
.Services.AddOptions<GraphApiOptions>()
    .Configure<IConfiguration>((settings, configuration) => configuration.GetSection("GraphApi").Bind(settings))
```

The values are in the `local.settings.json` just as they were before:

```
    "GraphApi:AuthenticationEndPoint": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "GraphApi:ClientId": "316f9726-0ec9-4ca5-8d04-f39966bebfe1",
    "GraphApi:ClientSecret": "VJ7qbWF-ek_Amb_e747nXW-fMOX-~6b8Y6",
    "GraphApi:EndPoint": "https://graph.microsoft.com/",
    "GraphApi:TenantId": "NuLicense.onmicrosoft.com",
```

Is this still supported?
What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, but turns out that the *json was not correctly formatted*.

Just for reference, here it is how I configured it:

```
var host = new HostBuilder()
            .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
            .ConfigureServices(s =>
            {
                s.AddOptions<ApplicationSettings>().Configure<IConfiguration>((settings, configuration) =>
                {
                    configuration.GetSection(nameof(ApplicationSettings)).Bind(settings);
                });
            })
            .Build();
```

And here is an example of local.setting.json:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "ApplicationSettings:test": "testtest",
    "ApplicationSettings:testtest": "test"
  }
}
```

Comment: How would you do it, if you didn't have a prefix for every appSetting? Like I have here in my local.settings.json:
 "Values": {
"AzureWebJobsStorage__accountName": "sazyrynkj6",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated",
    "QueueName_AccessEvent": "access-queue"
}

Comment: @OliverNilsen you can just use configuration.Bind(settings). e.g. services.AddOptions<MyConfig>().Configure<IConfiguration>((settings, configuration) => { configuration.Bind(settings); });

Answer (score 0):

I have updated environment variables from GetEnvironmentVariable to IOptions. Following steps I follows.

1. Include nuget packages

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureAppConfiguration" Version="6.0.1" />
```

2. Created a start up file and configure AddAzureAppConfiguration and AddOptions. "AppConfigVariables" is my class where I have declared my environment variables.

```
[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(MyApp.Startup))]
namespace MyApp
{
    public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void ConfigureAppConfiguration(IFunctionsConfigurationBuilder builder)
        {
            // Method intentionally left empty.
        }

        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Services.AddAzureAppConfiguration();
            builder.Services.AddOptions<AppConfigVariables>()
                             .Configure<IConfiguration>((settings, configuration) =>
                             {
                                 configuration.Bind(settings);
                             });
        
        }
    }
}
```

3. In Constructor you can access environment variables by invoking ioptions.

```
public class GetAllData
{
    private readonly AppConfigVariables appConfigVariables;
    
    public GetAllData(IOptions<AppConfigVariables> options)
    {
        appConfigVariables = options.Value;
        
    }
```

Let me know if it won't work for you.